# React Router Dom react js Blank white screen Show

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-component

I added React Router Dom in my project I want to show chat Area of Specific Area Group. So I am using React Router Dom to Access unique  Links
I used React Router Dom Version: 8.1
My Project

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import Chat from './components/Chat';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";


function App() {
  return (
    
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app_body">
      <Router>
        <Sidebar />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/">
              
              <Chat/>
            </Route>

          </Routes>
        </Router>
                    </div>
  </div>

    
  );
}

export default App;
```

After Run Result: Blank White screen showing Before using React Router Dom

Output
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `element` prop

```
import './App.css';
import Chat from './components/Chat';
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return ( 
    <div className="app">
      <div className="app_body">
          <Router>
            <Sidebar />
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Chat />} />
            </Routes>
          </Router>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Comment: <Route path='/' component={Chat} />

Comment: 8.1 is v6, no? the component prop was used until v5.